cant connect to public AWS RDS instance
In order to do a quick test, I need to connect to an RDS postgres instance.
I created a new free tier RDS DB, setting :

"Publicly accessible" to yes.
Self managed credentials with the default username of postgres and my own password.
Default DB subnet group (I have never created one). This group has 3 subnets for 3 regions, even though I only have the DB in one region.
Default VPC security group.
DB authentication of "password authentication".

However, when I try to connect with DBeaver, it always gives the connection timed out.
I would assume it to be firewall rules, but when I look at the database security groups, they seem to be open for all traffic.
Any ideas?


I don't know why there appear to be two duplicate inbound rules. Here is the detail of the first one:

$ nslookup database-2.c7xxxxxi.eu-north-1.rds.amazonaws.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Server:  GIVP0WIADC101.icepor.com
Address:  10.36.255.xxx

Name:    ec2-16-170-4xxx.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Address:  16.170.4x.xx
Aliases:  database-2.xxxxxxxeu-north-1.rds.amazonaws.com


